# Handlebars dynamic inline partial

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have a few lines of markup that I'd like to avoid keeping in an external partial file, but it should be rendered based on a variable value, either `IN_PROCESS` or `DONE`. I can make inline partials and render them based on static names:

```
{{#* inline  "IN_PROCESS"}}IN_PROCESS{{/inline}}
{{#* inline  "DONE"}}DONE{{/inline}}

{{> IN_PROCESS }}
{{> DONE }}
```

However I cannot figure out how to combine that with the `()` dynamic values syntax I have read about [here](https://zordius.github.io/HandlebarsCookbook/0028-dynamicpartial.html).

So something like,

```
{{> (data.status) }}
     └─────────┘ data.status would be either 'IN_PROCESS' or 'DONE'
```

#### Is this possible?

Comment: Do you just want to insert "IN_PROCESS" or "DONE" to the screen?

Comment: @Matt no those are the keys of the inline partials that in my real template would include more markup than just those strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something similar to this:

```
{{#* inline  "IN_PROCESS"}}IN_PROCESS{{/inline}}
{{#* inline  "DONE"}}DONE{{/inline}}

{{> (lookup . 'status')}}
```

`{{> (lookup . 'status')}}` will look through the JSON `data` object for its `status` attribute.
That is if you're passing your data in something like this:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(**your source**);
$('body').append(template(data));
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3m7pswue/2/)

The dot represents the data object that has been passed into the template function. The template function has no way of knowing what the object's name was:

```
template(inputData){
    // This function wouldn't know that inputData.status was originally data.status
}
var data = {status: "DONE"};
template(data);
```

The dot is therefore used to tell "template" when searching for a parent that inputData should be the parent and we're looking for "status" as a child. I believe that is the use of it. I actually can't find any documentation regarding its use but all lookup's seem to be in the format `lookup parent child` so I assume that's the reasoning.

Comment: I see, thank you. Will try when I get back to compy. What does the `.` signify in the lookup helper? I saw in the [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup)  also `lookup ../ @index`. What are these dots and slashes doing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0j8ykfut/ Yes, it seems that it's used to navigate through nested loops. Interesting. Thanks for your help. ✅